# Codeigniter loads controller/model pages very slowly locally

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter, visual-studio-code

I have an API I work with that has many moving parts to it. In Test/Stage and Production it runs fine. When I run it locally on my machine through a Docker container and vscode it is unbearably slow to access. If I hit individual endpoints through Postman then it's not as bad but from testing I have determined that there is about a 12 second delay before the endpoint is even hit. From my understanding it has to do with the controllers and loading all the necessary files (models) and whatever else it needs.

When I try and run the UI locally hitting my local API then it becomes a nightmare since usually the UI will access multiple endpoints to load a page and so I just sit there and wait forever. Most of the time it will take so long that my token will expire in the UI and I have to relog and start over and hope it doesn't happen again.

I know that the Linux subsystem could be playing a part since my repos are on the local filesystem, but I have tested running the repos from WSL and it's still very slow.

Also every time a call is made to the API Codeigniter will open and close the connection after each call which results in loading all the files for every call.

Is there a way to only have CI load all the files once and make multiple calls?

Is there any kind of vscode extension that could help with this?

Is there some cache changes I can make that might help?

Any advice that could point me in a different direction would be awesome.